# Had a chair for 5 year and management removed it?

Tags: work-environment

I work in an office and I usually sit down doing paper work. I work as a bookkeeper, my work is both standing and sitting depends on your department. I am the only one here in bookkeeping; other locations of the same company have chairs for their bookkeepers. I had a chair for 5 years, but my manager took it away saying it is not a sitting job. What can I do to get the chair back in the office?

Comment: Did your boss offer any sort of explanation after this? Was it just you this happened to?

Comment: So are you now expected to work standing up all day?  What is your actual job title?

Comment: Where are you located and do you have a medical condition that impedes your ability to stand for long periods of time?

Comment: From just this it seems the manager is a prat. We do need some more context though... Do you need the chair? Are they restricting you in any way?

Comment: I have back pains. No one at my job knows that I have them by sitting down it lessens the pain. I work as a bookkeeper. I was going to just ask my doctor to write a letter for me. Thank You for answering my question.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! Unfortunately, your question is unclear and will likely be put on hold. Please add some more information (as requested in comments). In particular: What exactly are your duties ("bookkeeping" is quite broad)? When do you usually sit down, and when do you work standing? Why did your manager take away the chair? Was there any stated reason beyond "not a sit-in job"?

Comment: Also, where are you?  Laws differ in different places.  In the US, I'd think the ADA would require the employer to give you a chair after getting the doctor's letter, but it may be different elsewhere.

Comment: I've never heard of standing book keeping, but honestly when your work environment deteriorates to the point of unhealthy, that's when it's time to leave.

Comment: What job would you be doing in an office that requires you to be standing? Adding that to the question will help the people answering.

Answer (score 6):

You should talk to your boss, explain your situation, ask for the reason of the chair being  taken and politely request your chair back.

When you request the chair be sure to explain that it helps with the pain, and focus on the part of not being a problem to develop your current activities.

Answer (score 3):

Your boss is either a prankster, an idiot or devious.

If you have a medical condition, it may make it easy to force the chair back.

If he is being difficult, you can explain, that bookkeeping is actually done a lot sitting, nowadays in front of the computer.

The following link rates bookkeeping on 124 with 83.7% sitting.

https://qz.com/922650/if-you-literally-never-want-to-sit-down-on-the-job-here-are-the-careers-for-you/amp/

Now he could have ulterior motives, maybe he wants to drive you out of employment or harasses you with this chair thing in some weird way.

Besides, I'm pretty sure unions and guilds have a thing or two to say about the idea of not providing chairs for employees.

So maybe find some literature on that in your locale to help you make the case next time you talk to him about getting the chair back.

Should he insist or maybe you come to like the idea of standing (which seems to have advantages) here is some info on desks and postures:

https://notsitting.com/proper-height/

https://www.posturite.co.uk/desks-furniture/height-adjustable-standing-desks.html